# Is it true that if $(a,b) = 1$, then $(2^a - 1, 2 ^ b -1) = 1$?

Tags: number-theory

I played around with some values and so far the conjecture seems to be true, however I haven't come up with a proof. I am not looking for a complete proof, only a couple of hints.

Comment: Hint: use the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: I think John McClane's hint is along the lines of: if $a = nb + r$, then $2^a - 1 = n' (2^b-1) + (2^r-1)$ for some $n'$; so as you go through the Euclidean algorithm on $a$ and $b$ you get parallel results for the Euclidean algorithm on $2^a - 1$ and $2^b - 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a,b$ are positive integers with $(a, b) = 1$.  Let us choose a Bezout pair $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ma + nb = 1$.  Now, suppose for the sake of illustration that $m > 0$ and $n < 0$.  Then $ma = 1 + (-n) b$, so $(2^a)^m = 2 \cdot (2^b)^{-n}$.  So, if $d \mid 2^a - 1$ and $d \mid 2^b - 1$, then $2^a \equiv 1 \pmod{d}$ and $2^b \equiv 1 \pmod{d}$...

Comment: Done and done thank you

Comment: Hmm. The issue I have here is that one of $m,n$ is negative.

Comment: @Joffan Ah, right, that was silly of me...  Edited to indicate how to adjust the argument for that.

Comment: The previous argument is still valid since in  any case $2$ will have an inverse $\pmod{d}$